# DIVs positioned absolute dissapear in scrollable DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a scrollable DIV that has lines of information (textarea's), as DIVs, 
one of top of another.

The scroll is something like 300 x 400 px, but it can have a lot of lines in it (DIV elements).

For each DIV line of information I have another small DIV that basically
lets an user click on YES / NO to delete that line of information.

I hide all of these "deletion" DIVs, but show only one of them, when
an user clicks on "delete" button for a particular line of information.

Problem comes because I position nicely the "deletion YES/NO div" above each line of information, with **position:absolute**. relative and fixed do not work well for me because they break the nice alignment I have in the "outer" DIV that holds all this.

For the 1st visible to the eye entries (lines of information) the "deletion" DIV for each of them looks ok (with position:absolute), but when I scroll down
the DIV, they don't show up no more. So this is the main problem.

How can I deal with this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to cast my "nicely done delete DIV", which I kept `position:absolute` into another DIV, which had set `position:relative`, just that, as styling.

This way the "outer" DIV positioned relative was keeping the track with the other elements in the main scrolling DIV, and the absolute which was inside it would now position nicely on top, with margin-left, or margin-top etc.

Comment: Could be better if you explain it a bit further!